# Include external resources in Ant build task

Tags: ant, resources, include, external, task

I have an Ant build script to generate some classes. The process requires an external library. Since I need this task for a lot of different modules I don't want to copy the lib everytime and I don't want to reference it localy as that would require all developers to download the lib first.
How do I reference and include an external resource? 
This is my setup so far

```
<project name="generate" basedir=".">

    <property name="src" location="src/main/java"/>
    <property name="generated" location="target/classes"/>
    <property name="build" location="src/main/java"/>

    <path id="cp">
        <fileset dir="path/to/lib" includes="**/querydsl-jpa-2.2.3-apt-one-jar.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="path/to/.m2" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>


  <target name="compile" >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="cp" includeantruntime="false">
      <compilerarg value="-proc:only"/>      
      <compilerarg value="-processor"/>
      <compilerarg value="com.mysema.query.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor"/>
      <compilerarg value="-s"/>
      <compilerarg value="${generated}"/>
    </javac>

    <!-- compilation -->
    <javac classpathref="cp" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="false">      
      <src path="${src}"/>
      <src path="${generated}"/>
    </javac>  
  </target>

</project>
```

Now I have the `querydsl-jpa-2.2.3-apt-one-jar.jar` at some remote location and I also want to reference our internal maven repository instead of the local .m2 directory, so I need to reference remote locations and include the libraries from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) Ant plug-in. It can help you in two ways:

1. Ivy can download libraries in the same manner as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
2. Your library is already available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.mysema.querydsl%7Cquerydsl-jpa%7C2.2.3%7Cjar) (No need to store it on your own website)

Developers using your project will only require the Ivy jar installed into one of the following locations:

- $HOME/.ant/lib
- $ANT_HOME/lib

## build.xml

The Ivy **resolve** task downloads (and caches) dependencies (found in the **ivy.xml** file). The **cachepath** task automatically populates the classpath:

```
<project name="generate" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <property name="src" location="src/main/java"/>
    <property name="generated" location="target/classes"/>
    <property name="build" location="src/main/java"/>

    <target name="resolve" >
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="cp" conf="compile"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="resolve">
    ..
```

## ivy.xml

Dependencies are declared here:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">

    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default"/>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Your jar -->
        <dependency org="com.mysema.querydsl" name="querydsl-jpa" rev="2.2.3" >
            <artifact name="querydsl-jpa" type="jar" m:classifier="apt-one-jar"/>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other Maven dependencies -->
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6"/>
        ..

    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

The **querydsl-jpa-2.2.3-apt-one-jar.jar** jar is special needs an additional [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) specification. If it was a Maven dependency it would be declared as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
    <classifier>apt-one-jar</classifier>
</dependency>
```

## ivysettings.xml

Ivy can be configured to use your Maven repository (Just like a Maven client):

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="maven-repo"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="maven-repo" m2compatible="true" root="http://myrepo.mycompany.com/maven-central-proxy"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Didn't notice your answer yesterday, so we have a workaround for our situation now. But might be, we'll have to rethink it.. 
Your answer sounds good, thanks! (though I don't much like the amount of local setup needed, especially having to configure the ivysettings).
Where do I place the ivy.xml? On the same level as the build.xml?

Comment: ivy.xml be default is located in the same directory as the build.xml. Maven too uses two files, one for project dependencies the other for environment settings.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the [Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks](https://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/).

This option is basically similar to using Ivy. The main differences:

- The dependencies are defined in the `build.xml` file instead of using a separate `ivy.xml` file.
- The downloaded dependencies are cached in a local Maven repository, where they can be used by other projects, including Maven based projects.
- The Maven repository can store multiple versions of the same artifact with no extra configuration.

The required steps:

1. Install the Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks uber JAR where ant can find it (like installing Ivy in the previous answer). The JAR can be downloaded from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-ant-tasks/1.3.0/maven-resolver-ant-tasks-1.3.0-uber.jar).
2. Add this attribute to the ant project definition:
   `xmlns:resolver="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant"`
3. Add a resolve target that identifies the artifacts you need and associates an identifier with the created classpath (see below).
4. As with Ivy, make your `javac` task depend on the `resolve` task and reference the classpath, e.g. `classpathref="cp"`

Here is the target to resolve using Maven:

```
<target name="resolve-maven">
    <resolver:resolve>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency coords="org.jetbrains:annotations:20.1.0"/>
      </dependencies>
      <path refid="cp" classpath="compile"/>
    </resolver:resolve>
</target>
```

For comparison, here is a similar target to resolve using Ivy:

```
<target name="resolve-ivy">
    <ivy:retrieve/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="cp" conf="compile"/>
</target>
```

If you like, put both of these in your `build.xml` and select one by name.

Comment: Apparently, you can get by without an ivy.xml file if you are willing to use the default configuration. That means you cannot separate compile time dependencies from compile and runtime dependencies. See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42305016/1652984].